# IntelliJ IDEA 2020 support for webdriverio selectors

Tags: intellij-idea, webdriver-io

I have this kind of code:

```
get alcoholLink() {
    return $('a=Alcohol');
}
```

which is valid webriverio selector for getting an element with text 'Alcohol'.
But IntelliJ IDEA underlines it red and displays "unexpected token" error.
Does anybody know how to tweak IntelliJ settings in order to recognize the code as valid webdriverio selector?

Thanks,
mismas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IDEA treats `$` as jQuery and thus `jQuery-CSS` language is auto-injected in `$()` calls. And `'a=Alcohol'` is not a valid CSS selector syntax - thus the error; deselecting the **js: JQuery selectors** language injection in **Settings | Editor | Language Injections** should help to get rid of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation :)